# How to fix files not uploading in PHP (uploading, but not moving, resulting in deletion)

Tags: php

I have a file upload system on my website. It's working fine. Well... sorta. I have it to move to a directory when it's done uploading. It's not working.

I've tried changing the values, putting quotes, etc

here's some code of it.

```
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$dir = "videos/".$user.;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
};
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "videos/" .$user. "/" .$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

before putting the `$dir`, this is my old code.

```
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$dir = "videos/".$user.;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
};
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], .$dir. "/" .$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the directory is being created?  Also, you have a typo... it should be: `$dir = "videos/" . $user;`  Note the lack of the second '.' character.

Comment: it didn't work... :( directory is fine. it's just the file

Comment: @electroner1998 hey, I think you have a typo... you have written _!empty($_FILES["userfile"])_ in your if condition  but in _move_uploaded_file(S_FILES['file']). i think the file name is wrong in your code

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: it worked! please put it as answer so I can count it.